# What is the most efficient way to delete/expire all messages in a Apache Pulsar topic?

Tags: apache-pulsar

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to remove all the messages from a Pulsar topic (either logically or physically), so that they are no longer consumable by subscriptions?

I know we can simply do `$ pulsar-admin persistent delete persistent://tenant/namespace/topic`.

But, this solution has some drawbacks: it removes the topic completely (so we have to recreate it later) then there should be no active client connected to it (i.e: subscriptions or producers).

Alternatively is there a way to programmatically make all messages between two MessageId unavailable to the subscriptions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of options you can choose from.

- You can use `topics skip` to skip N messages for a specific subscription of a given topic. https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/admin-api-persistent-topics/#skip-messages
- You can use `topics skip-all` to skip all the old messages for a specific subscription for a given topic. https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/admin-api-persistent-topics/#skip-all-messages
- You can use `topics clear-backlog` to clear the backlog of a specific subscription. It is same as `topics skip-all`.
- You can also use `topics reset-cursor` to move the subscription cursor to a specific message id or a timestamp back.

Answer (score 2):

From Sijie Guo's answer, I tried `skip-all`, but got:

> Expected a command, got skip-all
> Invalid command, please use `pulsar-admin --help` to check out how to use

I retried with `clear-backlog` with success.

https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/5685#issuecomment-664751216
The doc is updated here:
https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/pulsar-admin/#list-5
but not here:
https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/admin-api-topics#skip-all-messages
So it's confusing